# Pass data to hook_entity_insert

Tags: 7, entities

How can I pass data to `hook_entity_insert()` given that the arguments it takes are fixed?

I'm writing to the database during entity save, and need to be able to pass some data in this hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a property to the entity, which is then checked from [`hook_entity_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7.x). This isn't different from what the Book module does: [`book_node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21book%21book.module/function/book_node_load/7.x) adds a property to the node object (`node->book`), which is then retrieved from [`book_node_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21book%21book.module/function/book_node_insert/7.x).

```php
function book_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {book} b INNER JOIN {menu_links} ml ON b.mlid = ml.mlid WHERE b.nid IN (:nids)", array(
    ':nids' => array_keys($nodes),
  ), array(
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
  ));
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $nodes[$record['nid']]->book = $record;
    $nodes[$record['nid']]->book['href'] = $record['link_path'];
    $nodes[$record['nid']]->book['title'] = $record['link_title'];
    $nodes[$record['nid']]->book['options'] = unserialize($record['options']);
  }
}

function book_node_insert($node) {
  if (!empty($node->book['bid'])) {
    if ($node->book['bid'] == 'new') {
      // New nodes that are their own book.
      $node->book['bid'] = $node->nid;
    }
    $node->book['nid'] = $node->nid;
    $node->book['menu_name'] = book_menu_name($node->book['bid']);
    _book_update_outline($node);
  }
}
```

The Book module is implementing `hook_node_insert()` instead of `hook_entity_insert()`. The difference between those hooks is that the first is invoked when a node is created, after the node is saved in the database, while the latter is invoked when any entity is created, after than entity is saved in the database. `hook_entity_insert()` also has the entity type as parameter, while
`hook_node_insert()` doesn't have that parameter (since it knows which entity type is being saved).
What I described can be used for both the hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not initiating the hook, you'll have to find another way. Maybe call a hook in the hook you're implementing?

If you would've been initiating the hook, you could've just passed on more parameters and used [func_get_args](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to get the parameters, ie:

```
function sum ($a, $b) {
  $sum = 0;
  foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
    $sum += $arg;
  }
}
```

and call it with

```
sum(1, 2, 3, 4)
```